# Raspberry Pi Pico -- Read USB Midi Input

Tags: usb, pi-pico, midi

I'm new to programming with Raspberry Pi's. I have a Yamaha p45 electric keyboard that outputs MIDI over a USB cable (not the 5-pin midi cable) and I need to read the midi input into my Raspberry Pi Pico. I've been doing research for weeks but it looks like maybe it's not possible to get USB MIDI input on the pico? All I can find is MIDI *output* or MIDI input using the 5-pin midi cable or MIDI input in some other type of Raspberry Pi that isn't the pico.

Does anyone know how I could approach this? Maybe there's some way I could use the UART pins instead of the micro USB port? Could I cut open the MIDI cable to expose the inner wires and attach those to the UART pins? Any and all help would be much appreciated!

Comment: Yes, uart midi is much easier than usb. This might help: https://forums.raspberrypi.com/viewtopic.php?t=225387

Comment: But for P45 with USB interface only, the easy way it to use USB. References: (1) 
Yahama Digital Piano P45 Owner Manual
https://www.musikkhandel.no/media/files/2496/p45_en_om_a0.pdf

(2) USB & MIDI: Everything you need to know to get it right (USB MIDI Host vs Interface explained) - loopop
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=neXswJJcatc&t=649s

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I ended up doing was receiving the MIDI from my Mac and then just sending that as raw data to my Raspberry Pi Pico through USB. It was kind of a round-about way to solve the problem but in the end it was the only way I could get it to work, and with my current setup it works just fine.

Answer (score 0):

To be able to access a USB device, you would need to use the Pico in USB Host mode.

The Pico uses the [TinyUSB](https://github.com/hathach/tinyusb) stack; in host mode, it does not support MIDI.